# How to check if a specifik word is written as a part og the test in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

How to check if a specifik word is written as a part og the test in a textbox?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. 
Let's say, you've a textbox with id mytext and you want to know the existence of the specific word 'specificWOrd' in the textbox then you can do the following:

```
       var wordToSearch = 'specificWOrd',
         mytext = document.getElementById('mytext'),
         pattern = new RegExp('(\\W|^)' + wordToSearch + '(\\W|$)'),
         txt = mytext.value;

       if(txt && txt.search(pattern) !== -1){
          console.log('found');
       }
```

OR it can also be done the following way:

```
       var wordToSearch = 'specificWOrd',
         mytext = document.getElementById('mytext'),
         pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + wordToSearch + '\\b'),
         txt = mytext.value;

       if(txt && txt.search(pattern) !== -1){
          console.log('found');
       }
```

Comment: Yah! this will work

Comment: Why don't you use word boundaries?

Comment: Yah! word boundaries can also be used.

Comment: It seem very legit, however i cant make it work

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, where `String.indexOf()` is the simplest one. Which gives the index occurrence starting from `0`, if match found else `-1`. Below example, looks for word `on`.

```html
<input type="text" autofocus='' value='there goes a very long text' oninput="console.log(this.value.indexOf('on'));" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. You can use  yourstring.indexOf(str) to check if the str is present in your string. Here is the mdn link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Most likely--we don't actually know--he wants to detect **words**, whereas your solution would find any string occurring **inside** a word.

Comment: I would like if we have an empty textbox, then i could as a person get on this site, poste some text and then the site would tell me if the word "dog"(exempel) is in the text.

Comment: He wants to detect words @torazaburo